# 3D Projection Modification - Encode Z/W into Z

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, linear-algebra

This is a little tricky to explain, so bare with me. I'm attempting to design a 2D projection matrix that takes 2D pixel coordinates along with a custom world-space depth value, and converts to clip-space.

The idea is that it would allow drawing elements based on screen coordinates, but at specific depths, so that these elements would interact on the depth buffer with normal 3D elements. However, I want `x` and `y` coordinates to remain the same scale at every depth. I only want depth to influence the depth buffer, and not coordinates or scale.

After the vertex shader, the GPU sets `depth_buffer=z/w`. However, it also scales `x/w` and `y/w`, which creates the depth scaling I want to avoid. This means I must make sure my final clip-space `w` coordinate ends up being `1.0`, to avoid those things. I think I could also adopt to scale `x` and `y` by `w`, to cancel out the divide, but I would rather do the former, if possible.

This is the process that my 3D projection matrix uses to convert depth into clip space (`d` = depth, `n` = near distance, `f` = far distance)

```
z = f/(f-n) * d + f/(f-n) * -n;
w = d;
```

This is how I would like to setup my 2D projection matrix. Compared to the 3D version, it would divide both attributes by the input depth. This would simulate having `z/w` encoded into just the `z` value.

```
z = ( f/(f-n) * d + f/(f-n) * -n ) / d;
w = d / d;
```

I think this turns into something like..

```
r = f/(f-n); // for less crazy math
z = r + ( r * -n ) / d;
w = 1.0;
```

However, I can't seem to wrap my math around the values that I would need to plug into my matrix to get this result. It looks like I would need to set my matrix up to perform a division by depth. Is that even possible? Can anyone help me figure out the values I need to plug into my matrix at `m[2][2]` and `m[3][2]` (`m._33` and `m._43`) to make something like this happen?

Note my 3D projection matrix uses the following properties to generate the final `z` value:

```
m._33 = f / (f-n); // depth scale
m._43 = -(f / (f-n)) * n; // depth offset
```

**Edit:** After thinking about this a little more, I realized that the rate of change of the depth buffer is not linear, and I'm pretty sure a matrix can only perform linear change when its input is linear. If that is the case, then what I'm trying to do wouldn't be possible. However, I'm still open to any ideas that are in the same ball park, if anyone has one. I know that I can get what I want by simply doing `pos.z /= pos.w; pos.w = 1;` in the vertex shader, but I was really hoping to make it all happen in the projection matrix, if possible.

Comment: Perspective projection `1/w` or process to cancel them `x * w` are non-linear algebra, it cannot be achieved only with linear algebra.

Comment: Yep, I realized that after spending too much time trying to come up with a solution. The same is true when applying perspective divide to x and y.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is attempting to do this, it cannot be done. Without black magic, there is apparently no way to divide values with a matrix, unless of course the diviser is a constant or etc, where you can swap out a scaler with `1/x`. I resorted to performing the operation in the shader in the end.